# Xquery Finding max difference out of all elements

Tags: xquery

I am trying to find a maximum difference from an element in an XML document.

So, from the example data below, id want the maximum difference of years from a movie. The difference between years in the first movie is 2 years, whereas the maximum difference from the 2nd movie is 3 years. So from this data I would return 3.

```
<Movie>
    <Name></Name>
    <Year>1990</Year>
    <Language>
        <Name></Name>
        <Year>1992</Year>
    </Language>
</Movie>
<Movie>
    <Name></Name>
    <Year>2006</Year>
    <Language>
        <Name></Name>
        <Year>2004</Year>
    </Language>
    <Language>
        <Name></Name>
        <Year>2003</Year>
    </Language>
    <Language>
        <Name></Name>
        <Year>2006</Year>
    </Language>
</Movie>
```

Comment: What version of XQuery and what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
max(//Language/abs(number(../Year)-number(Year)))
```

Comment: Ah, that's exactly what I need! It worked for a small data set that i used (25 elements or so). However, when I tried to use it on my larger data set (256000 elements) it returns 0. Not sure if that's because there is an oddity or something in the data or some other issue.

Comment: So I took out "max" and it showed me all 256000 differences. There were many values exceeding 40, so I'm unsure why it selects 0 as the maximum. Any ideas?

Comment: No ideas. You need to post a reproducible example. If you suspect a product bug, (a) say what product you are using, (b) try it on a different product, (c) contact the vendor.